# Dúvida SQL Server 2012 - Query

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Estou com uma dificuldade. Na consulta abaixo, está trazendo dessa forma.

> ```
> Tarefa_Inclusao      Tarefa
> 167909               167920
> ```

```
SELECT TarIDInclusao [Tarefa_Inclusao],tarid [Tarefa] FROM Tarefa WHERE TarID = 167920.
```

Nessa consulta é outra tarefa.  O que eu quero é o seguinte: Quero que na consulta acima, realizar uma manipulação para que o campo tarefa_inclusao em vez de vir 167909, venha 167907 igual da consulta abaixo.

> ```
> Tarefa_Inclusao      Tarefa
> 167907               167909
> ```

```
SELECT TarIDInclusao [Tarefa_Inclusao],tarid [Tarefa] FROM Tarefa WHERE TarID = 167909
```

Comment: Você quer a tarefa "mãe" de todas a partir da que você colocou no `WHERE`. É isso? A tarefa primordial possui o que na coluna `tarefa_inclusao`?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Sorack. É assim: A tarefa mãe é essa: 167907, as outras como 167909,167920 são filhas, ou seja, o campo tarefa_inclusao das filhas é justamente a tarefa mãe que no caso é a 167907.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize uma busca recursiva para encontrar o registro primordial para a tarefa desejada:

```
WITH historico AS (
  SELECT t.taridinclusao AS tarefa_inclusao,
         t.tarid AS tarefa,
         1 AS nivel
    FROM tarefa t
   WHERE t.tarid = 167920
   UNION ALL
  SELECT t.taridinclusao AS tarefa_inclusao,
         h.tarid AS tarefa, -- Pega do historico para garantir que o primeiro valor será mostrado
         h.nivel + 1 AS nivel
    FROM historico h
         INNER JOIN tarefa t ON t.tarid = h.taridinclusao
   WHERE h.taridinclusao IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT TOP(1) h.*
  FROM historico h
 ORDER BY h.nivel DESC
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0);
```

O primeiro `SELECT` dentro do `WITH` irá definir a ancoragem dos registros, ou seja, o registro da qual partiremos, neste caso a tarefa da qual temos o número. Após isso, iremos sempre referenciar a própria `historico` para verificar o registro `taridinclusao` referente a ele.

> [`WITH`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)
>
> Uma CTE (expressão de tabela comum) fornece a significativa vantagem de ser capaz de se autorreferenciar, criando, portanto uma CTE recursiva. Uma CTE recursiva é aquela em que uma CTE inicial é executada repetidamente para retornar subconjuntos de dados até que o resultado completo seja obtido.

Comment: Peguei essa sua consulta e veio dessa forma 
Tarefa_Inclusao     Tarefa          Nivel
Null                          167907         3

Porém, era para vir dessa forma

Tarefa_Inclusao     Tarefa          Nivel
167907                  167920           3

Comment: @RenanBessa por isso perguntei como estava o último registro no meu comentário na sua pergunta. Vou editar para corresponder a esta nova informação.

Comment: @RenanBessa alterado. Verifique por favor.

Comment: ainda veio da mesma forma.
Tarefa_Inclusao     Tarefa
167909                    167920

Era para vir:

Tarefa_Inclusao     Tarefa
167907                   167920

Comment: @RenanBessa corrigido

Comment: O responsável pelo `downvote` pode explicitar o que está incorreto na resposta? Apenas o `downvote` sem explicação acaba sendo inútil.

Comment: tu é fera demais. Muitissimo obg pela sua ajuda. Abraços.